# Vulkan specialization constants in WGSL

Tags: vulkan, wgsl

I'm converting my shaders from GLSL to WGSL. I'm a little bit confused about how to define [Vulkan Specialization Constants](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#pipelines-specialization-constants) in the WGSL shader language.

In GLSL, for example, I might write:

```c
layout (constant_id = 2) const float foobar = 0.1f;
```

What's the equivalent syntax in WGSL, or is this unsupported by the language?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `override` declarations. (https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#override-decls)

`@id(2) override foobar: f32 = 0.1f`